# Why is maven not showing lenskin artifact?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lenskit

I have been to trying to run lenskit with eclipse, I have got eclipse and maven running. I am referring to this documentation
[link](https://github.com/grouplens/lenskit/wiki/GettingStarted)

It says that

> Select ‘File → New → Project …’. In the New Project dialog make sure ‘Create a simple project’ is unchecked, so you can choose an archetype. On the next dialog click the box ‘Include snapshot archetypes’ if you want the latest lenskit archetypes, and filter for ‘lenskit’. Choose the lenskit archetype you want to use to create your project.

But in my case, nothing shows up, when I enter lenskit in the filter box. Am I supposed to update something.
[image]

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with IntelliJ, and it worked. I don't say that to rub it in but just to point out that the problem isn't on the repo side. It could be that Eclipse is looking at some default or common list of archetypes, and LensKit isn't among them. Try the `Add Archetype` button and provide

- archetypeGroupId=org.grouplens.lenskit
- archetypeArtifactId=lenskit-archetype-simple-analysis
- archetypeVersion=2.0

and see what happens.